# How can I submit a form on input change without getting the input value stuck?

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically set a grid using the values from a pair of range input sliders. Basically, what I'm doing at the moment is putting them in a form so that I can submit it each time there is an input change. However, this isn't a solution because every time I try to change it, it submits the form and hence the input slider is "stuck".

```
<form id='chartSize' method='get'>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <pre>Rows:   </pre>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="10" class="slider" name="rows" id="rows" 
        oninput="changeDimensions(true)">
        <output name="rowOutputName" id="rowOutputId"></output><br/>
        <pre>Columns:</pre>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="10" class="slider" name="columns" id="columns"
        oninput="changeDimensions(false)">
        <output name="colOutputName" id="colOutputId"></output><br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: The changeDimensions script actually is relevant to the problem.

Here it is:

```
function changeDimensions(opt)
{
    if(opt==true)
    {
        rowOutputId.value = rows.value;
    }
    else
    {
        colOutputId.value = columns.value;
    }

    document.getElementById('chartSize').submit();
}
```

Comment: Attach a listener to the form `submit` event and `preventDefault`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just added the changeDimensions script to the question. How could I modify it so that it works correctly?

Comment: I don't understand - do you want to submit the form (which will replace the page), or do you just want to display the changes to the `<output>` elements on change? It doesn't make much sense to do both

Comment: @CertainPerformance go to this page and click on the show options button: [link](https://www.neverendingchartrendering.org/) . Then change the rows and columns by dragging the slider. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to use a `form` in this situation is to provide accessibility: the *usual* reason to use a form is to give the user the ability to input values and to then send those values to a server. You're not doing that - all you need to do is to get the inputted values and use them, while *not ever submitting the form*.

Also, you shouldn't add Javascript handlers inside your HTML - they're essentially `eval` inside HTML markup, and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Attach listeners with Javascript instead:

```js
const rowOutputId = document.querySelector('#rowOutputId');
const colOutputId = document.querySelector('#colOutputId');
const rows = document.querySelector('#rows');
const columns = document.querySelector('#columns');
rows.addEventListener('change', () => rowOutputId.value = rows.value);
columns.addEventListener('change', () => colOutputId.value = columns.value);
```

```html
<form id='chartSize' method='get'>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <pre>Rows:   </pre>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" class="slider" id="rows">
    <output id="rowOutputId"></output><br/>
    <pre>Columns:</pre>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" class="slider" id="columns">
    <output id="colOutputId"></output><br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to prevent submission of the form.

```
document.getElementById('chartSize').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. go to this page and click on the show options button: [link](https://www.neverendingchartrendering.org/). Then change the rows and columns by dragging the slider. That's what I'm trying to do.